# How to select Multiple Files using File Upload and Uploading those files to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am doing a Project of Uploading the files to SQL Server and then Download it I want to Select Multiple files to be Selected and Uploaded at a Single Click but Presently a Single File is selected and Uploaded both to FTP Server and SQL Server, could any one Suggest me a link or Sample Code to Select Multiple Files and Upload it to SQL Server

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `FileUpload.PostedFiles` Property

Try with following code:

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile upFile in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
{
    SaveFiles(upFile);
}

private void SaveFiles(HttpPostedFile fObj)
{
   using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))// set ConnectionString
   {
       using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(DatabaseQuery,con)) // set appropriate query
       {
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", ReadFile(fObj));
          con.Open();
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
   }
}

private byte[] ReadFile(HttpPostedFile fObj2)
{
    byte[] data = new Byte[fObj2.ContentLength];
    fObj2.InputStream.Read(data, 0, file.ContentLength);
    return data;
}
```

**MSDN:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfiles.aspx

Hope Its Helpful.

Comment: @ Freelancer As My system OS is XP only i can't Install .Net Framework 4.5 to access Fileupload.postedfiles So, I found some Jquery to select multiple files and used your RReadFile(HttpPostedFile fObj2)
 to read the file and Upload it in SQL Server

Comment: @Rajesh If permited, you can use telerik controls for this purpose, inbuilt functionality for multiple file upload is there.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to use the AllowMultiple attribute (supported by .Net 4.5):

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="MyFileUpload" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
```

You can now select multiple files with ALT/STRG to be uploaded. Then use Freelancer´s code.

Comment: @ AGuyCalledGerald
i had only XP installed in my System so I can't use the AllowMultiple which was Supported by .Net 4.5 so I used the Jquery to select Multiple files and used Freelancers ReadFile(HttpPostedFile fObj2)
to read and Upload files in SQL Server